# self contained asp.net core app runs fine when started via command line,- but when started as service under linux it crashes immediately

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, service, crash

I have a self-contained ASP.net core app which works fine when started via command line on Linux Ubuntu.

If I try to start the same app as a service, it starts but crashes immediately.

The service file looks like this:

---

```
[UNIT]
Description=.....

[Service]
workingDirectory=/etc/www/api
ExecStart=/etc/www/api/API.Web

User=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

---

Hint: I just used root as user for demo purposes. When going live this will be a dedicated user with limited rights. --> It also does not work with a specific user with limited rights.

The crash error message when doing service  status is:

---

[image: ErrorMessage]

What could cause such a strange behavior and how to avoid it.

Comment: Hard to say with the information provided. However, `signal=ABRT` usually indicates that the process is self-terminating due to a failed internal check, e.g. an expected requirement is not fulfilled... (missing terminal, missing display, whatever).

Comment: Which port does this application attempt to bind to? Root permission is required if it wants port number smaller than 1024. You should try port numbers such as 5000.

Comment: @Lex Li, it is 5001 - but it also crashes when using the root user